# WP All Export: how to pass exported data through PHP function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm trying to build custom export column in WP All Export but I can not get what I'm trying to achieve. I need column 'For Payment', where I need to place actual order total in case the payment method is COD. Otherwise it should return 0 (required by couriers). I tried to modify code below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
function cod_payment( $order_id ) {
    $total = get_total();
    $method = get_payment_method();
    if($method == "cod") {
        return $total;
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
?>
```

[image: Edit Export Field dialogue in WP All Export]

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. select `Custom export field` add the function call in the text area

```
[cod_payment({Payment Method},{Order Total})]
```

and finaly the PHP to the function editor (make sure to save it)

```
<?php
function cod_payment( $method, $total ) {

    if($method == "cod") {
        return $total;
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
?>
```

Keep in mind the method name may not be correct.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hm, I tested this and I must have payment method title column included. Is there a maybe a way to avoid it? I just need "for payment" column

Comment: hi sorry the screenshot is incorrect I changed the code to have the correct fields, the payment method is located under "Other"

Answer (score 0):

> I need column 'For Payment'

So the value of the `Column name` text field should be "For Payment", not "Order Total".

Also, in order for the PHP function to be called, you need to specify its name in the text field between `<?php` and `($value); ?>`. It should be "cod_payment", not "cliente_jr".

Finally, why isn't the `$order_id` being used inside the function? I assume you need it to fetch the total and the payment method, possibly something like this:

```
<?php
function cod_payment( $order_id ) {
    $total = get_total( $order_id );
    $method = get_payment_method( $order_id );
    if($method == "cod") {
        return $total;
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did everything like you but I get an error "An unknown error occured"... Can not figure out what exactly is wrong. I'm dealing with this plugin first time :/

Comment: Try turning on debugging to see if there are errors in the `wp-content/debug.log` file:  https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/